# Оптимизация олимпиадной задачи

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, олимпиада

Есть задача:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально я написал код на питоне, получилось так:

```
from array import array


def string_xor(a: str, b: str):
    """
    Проверка на схожесть строк
    3 - одинаковые
    2 - 1 различие
    1 - больше 2 отличий
    """
    k = len(a)
    if k == len(b):
        a1 = array('u', a)
        b1 = array('u', b)
        errors = 0
        for i in range(k):
            if a1[i] != b1[i]:
                errors += 1
        if errors > 1:
            return 1
        elif errors == 1:
            return 2
        elif errors == 0:
            return 3
    return 1


n, m = map(int, input().split())
words = sorted(input() for _ in range(n))
for _ in range(m):
    word = input()
    one_diff = []  # Список слов, которые расходятся ровно на одну букву
    for cur in words:
        ans = string_xor(word, cur)
        if ans == 3:
            print(cur)
            break
        elif ans == 2:
            one_diff.append(cur)
    else:
        if one_diff:
            print(min(one_diff))
        else:
            print('?')
```

Но он валится на одном из тестов по времени. Дальше я переписал его на плюсы, думая, что это поможет.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"
using namespace std;

int check(string a, string b) {
    int k = a.size();
    if (k == b.size()) {
        int errors(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            errors += a[i] != b[i];
        if (errors == 0)
            return 0;
        else if (errors == 1)
            return 1;
        return 2;
    }
    return 2;
}

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    string word;
    vector <string> words(n), one_diff;
    for (string &el : words)
        cin >> el;
    sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cin >> word;
        bool is_break(false);
        for (const string &cur : words) {
            int d = check(cur, word);
            if (d == 0) {
                cout << cur << "\n";
                is_break = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (d == 1)
                one_diff.push_back(cur);
        }
        if (!is_break) {
            if (!one_diff.empty()) {
                sort(one_diff.begin(), one_diff.end());
                cout << one_diff[0] << "\n";
                one_diff.clear();
            }
            else
                cout << "?" << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Но это не помогло, валится на том же тесте.
Подскажите, что тут надо изменить, чтобы программа укладывалась по времени.

Сделал словарь с длинами строк, было время 1.033, стало 1.09
код:

```
from array import array


def string_xor(a: str, b: str):
    k = len(a)
    if k == len(b):
        errors = 0
        for a1, b1 in zip(a, b):
            errors += a1 != b1
        if errors > 1:
            return 1
        elif errors == 1:
            return 2
        elif errors == 0:
            return 3
    return 1


n, m = map(int, input().split())
d = {}
for _ in range(n):
    word = input()
    z = len(word)
    d[z] = d.get(z, [word]) + [word]
for i in d.keys():
    d[i].sort()
for _ in range(m):
    word = input()
    one_diff = set()
    try:
        for cur in d[len(word)]:
            ans = string_xor(word, cur)
            if ans == 3:
                print(cur)
                break
            elif ans == 2:
                one_diff.add(cur)
        else:
            if one_diff:
                print(min(one_diff))
            else:
                print('?')
    except KeyError:
        print('?')
```

PS Код валится именно по времени...
PPS Сорян, ссылку на задачу дать не могу.

Comment: Если валится по времени - как идея - предлагаю попробовать разделить слова на группы по числу букв и проверять только те, у которых длина одинакова. Так сказать, индексировать по двум параметрам. (Прочие вы все равно не проверяете). Если бы был неверный ответ - я бы посоветовал проверять и слова иной длины: например, в словаре - `word`, у вас - `words`. Отличие в 1 букву... Да, URL не дадите - поиграться?

Comment: Во первых,  вы имеете условие, что  в каждой строке по одному слову, размера не превышающую 20 символов, а значит (ИМХО) вполне уместно не использовать контейнеры, а работать с символьными массивами char[21]. Ну а дальше написать оптимальную функцию сравнения и т.д.

Comment: Ну вот, двадцать массивов - почти хеширование :) Кстати, передавая в `check` строки по ссылке, вы уже ускорите программу...

Comment: Прикольно, что разрешённой памяти хватает на словарь всех слов с одной ошибкой

Comment: В коде на C++ сразу бросается в глаза эпический фейл - передача строк по значению. А вообще это больше похоже на задачу для построения префиксного дерева. Перебирать все подряд - почти всегда является плохой идеей.

Comment: @Null , закинь эту задачу на https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ пусть ребята там поиграются :)

Comment: можно ли использовать сторонние библиотеки? (для python)

Comment: Есть какая-то проверялка? Или хотя бы набор тестов, чтоб смотреть на правильность и время работы?

Comment: @Jack_oS, к сожалению нет, только чистый Python 3.7

Comment: да о какой секунде вообще может идти речь при сравнении 100.000 на 100.000 при длине слова 20 букв, тем более например если все слова не совпадают, а если посмотреть на код автора и то что он пишет что у него что то там выполняется за 1.033 сек, то вообще непонятно что он там и как считает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Алгоритм

Для каждого слова длины `k` вычисляется `k + 1` хешей. Один для всего слова, остальные для всех вариантов слова без одной буквы. Буквы не вычеркиваются, (виртуально) заменяются на символ вне алфавита. Так меньше коллизий.

Индексы слов помещаются в рукописную хеш-таблицу. Размер таблицы равен общему числу хешей для всех слов словаря. Другими словами в таблице нет свободных ячеек.

```
Word     words[n]           // слова словаря
uint32_t index[ht_size + 1] // метки в следующей таблице
uint32_t table[ht_size]     // индексы слов

// этот код перебирает все слова в словаре с хешем `h`
for (uint32_t i = index[h]; i < index[h + 1]; ++i) {
    words[table[i]];
}
```

После создания таблицы, для каждого проверяемого слова вычисляется `k + 1` хеш. Все слова соответствующие хешам проверяются на возможное равенство или равенство без одного символа.

### Память для словаря

Словарь в котором все слова по `20` символов. Размер файла не превосходит 2MB. Число слов тогда `n < 100000`. Структура для хранения слова требует `21` байт на слово. Число хешей `2100000 = (1 + 20) * 100000`.

```
words[ 100000] // 2100000B (2.1MB)
index[2100001] // 8400004B (8.4MB)
table[2100000] // 8400000B (8.4MB)
```

Всего `19MB`.

Самое большое число слов, которое можно поместить в в файл размером `2MB` - это `1 + 26 + 26**2 + 26**3 + 404953 = 423232`. Все различные слова длиной ноль, один, два и три и остаток слова длины четыре. Такой словарь займёт в памяти `423232 * 21 = 8887872` байт. Не более `9MB`. Максимальное потребное число хешей не более `423232 + 2 * 1024 * 1024 = 2520384`. Суммарная память не более `9MB + 10MB + 10MB = 29MB`.

### Производительность

Для всех протестированных словарей время работы не более одной секунды на неоптимизированной сборке GCC. Возможно что-то упущенно. Были испробованы словари на 230000 слов до четырех символов и на 50000 слов по двадцать символов. Скорость зависит от качества хеширования, которое в свою очередь должно быть быстрым. Хеш функция была подсмотрена в Boost.

Подбором слов в словаре можно пытаться замедлить программу. Слов до 20 символов около `2 * 10^28`, ясно что из них для любой хеш таблицы, которая помещается в 64MB, можно подобрать такие слова что все они окажутся в одной корзине.

### Код

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror proofreading.cpp

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

const int max_size = 20;

void fail() {
    std::fprintf(stderr, "ERROR\n");
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void skip_line() {
    for (; ; ) {
        int c = std::getc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF) {
            fail();
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
            break;
        }
    }
}

class Word {
public:
    void scan() {
        if (std::fgets(data, max_size + 1, stdin) == nullptr) {
            fail();
        }
        const size_t len = std::strlen(data);
        if (len == 0) {
            fail();
        }
        if (data[len - 1] == '\n') {
            data[len - 1] = '\0';
        } else {
            skip_line();
        }
    }

    void print() const {
        std::fputs(data, stdout);
    }

    size_t length() const {
        return std::strlen(data);
    }

    uint32_t hash() const {
        uint32_t seed = 0;
        hash(seed, data);
        return seed;
    }

    uint32_t hash(size_t skip) const {
        uint32_t seed = 0;
        hash(seed, skip, data);
        hash(seed, static_cast<char>(skip));
        hash(seed, data + (skip + 1));
        return seed;
    }

    bool eq(const Word &w) const {
        return std::strcmp(data, w.data) == 0;
    }

    bool eq(const Word &w, size_t skip) const {
        return
            length() == w.length() &&
            std::memcmp(data             , w.data             , skip) == 0 &&
            std::strcmp(data + (skip + 1), w.data + (skip + 1)      ) == 0
        ;
    }

    bool lt(const Word &w) const {
        return std::strcmp(data, w.data) < 0;
    }


private:
    char data[max_size + 1];

    static void hash(uint32_t &seed, char c) {
        seed ^= static_cast<unsigned char>(c) + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }

    static void hash(uint32_t &seed, size_t n, const char data[/* n */]) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            hash(seed, data[i]);
        }
    }

    static void hash(uint32_t &seed, const char data[]) {
        for (const char *p = data; *p != '\0'; ++p) {
            hash(seed, *p);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    int n, m;

    if (std::scanf("%d %d", &n, &m) != 2) {
        fail();
    }
    skip_line();

    std::vector<Word> words(n);
    size_t ht_size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        words[i].scan();
        ht_size += 1 + words[i].length();
    } 

    std::vector<uint32_t> index(ht_size + 1, 0);
    for (const Word &w : words) {
        ++index[w.hash() % ht_size];
        const size_t length = w.length();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            ++index[w.hash(i) % ht_size];
        }
    } 

    {
        uint32_t acc = 0;
        for (uint32_t &i : index) {
            acc += i;
            i = acc;
        }
    }

    for (int i = ht_size; i > 0; --i) {
        index[i] = index[i - 1];
    }
    index[0] = 0;

    std::vector<uint32_t> table(ht_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        const Word &w = words[i];
        uint32_t &j = index[w.hash() % ht_size];
        table[j++] = i;
        const size_t length = w.length();
        for (size_t k = 0; k < length; ++k) {
            uint32_t &j = index[w.hash(k) % ht_size];
            table[j++] = i;
        }
    } 

    for (int i = ht_size; i > 0; --i) {
        index[i] = index[i - 1];
    }
    index[0] = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        Word w;
        w.scan();

        {
            const uint32_t h = w.hash() % ht_size;
            const uint32_t i1 = index[h];
            const uint32_t i2 = index[h + 1];
            uint32_t i;
            for (i = i1; i < i2; ++i) {
                 if (w.eq(words[table[i]])) {
                     break;
                 }
            }
            if (i < i2) {
                w.print();
                std::puts("");
                continue;
            }
        }

        {
            const Word *best_match = nullptr;
            const size_t length = w.length();
            for (size_t k = 0; k < length; ++k) {
                const uint32_t h = w.hash(k) % ht_size;
                const uint32_t i1 = index[h];
                const uint32_t i2 = index[h + 1];
                for (uint32_t i = i1; i < i2; ++i) {
                    const Word &ww = words[table[i]];
                    if (w.eq(ww, k)) {
                        if (best_match == nullptr || ww.lt(*best_match)) {
                            best_match = &ww;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (best_match != nullptr) {
                best_match->print();
                std::puts("");
            } else {
                std::puts("?");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Это решение не учитывает необходимость нахождения *лексикографически минимального* слова, отличающегося на одну букву. Например при входе `4 1 
aos
cos
eos
gos
dos` оно выдает `aos`, хотя это слово отличается больше, чем `cos`

Comment: А `aos` в данном случае не правильный ответ? `aos < cos`.

Comment: Я не оп и проверить не могу, но по идее нет. Отличие должно считаться от `dos`, а не от `cos`

Comment: Я не понимаю почему ответом в вашем примере должен быть `cos`.

Comment: Потому что лексикографически `cos` ближе к `dos`, чем `aos`.

Comment: Я по другому прочитал условия. Все четыре слова на расстоянии единица от `dos`. Из всех четырех кандидатов, я выбираю минимального (в этом выборе `dos` уже не участвует). Я понял вашу идею, но пока не знаю кто из нас прав.

Comment: Термин лексикографически минимальное слово подразумевает, что оно само по себе минимальное, поэтому aos. О минимизации разности различающихся символов речи не шло.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
from jellyfish import levenshtein_distance


def orthography(word, vocabulary):
    if word in vocabulary:
        return word

    for v_word in sorted(vocabulary):
        if levenshtein_distance(word, v_word) == 1:
            return v_word

    return '?'

for word in words:
    print(orthography(word, vocabulary))
```

тогда для таких данных:

```
vocabulary = ['a', 'love', 'contexts', 'math']
words = ['i', 'love', 'programming', 'contests']
```

выведет следующее:

```
a
love
?
contexts
```

а для второго тест-кейса:

```
vocabulary = ['ac', 'ab']
words = ['aa']
```

ответом будет:

```
ab
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, jellyfish - это не встроенная библиотека, а задача все-таки олимпиадная и пакеты, кроме стандартных не предусмотрены. Кроме того, решением олимпиадной задачи, как мне лично кажется, является не код, а конкретный алгоритм, так что "черные коробки" бессмысленны.

Comment: Алгоритм имеет сложность `MN`, где `M` - размер словаря, `N` - размер текста. По времени не уложится.

Comment: В данном конкретном случае "расстояние по Левенштейну" пишется элементарно. Внешние библиотеки не нужны. Надо сосчитать отличающиеся буквы за один проход. Сложность - вот проблема.

Comment: @EzikBro можно посмотреть, как [реализован метод](https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish/blob/main/jellyfish/_jellyfish.py) библиотеки, конечно, но, боюсь, даже в случае использовании того алгоритма может "валится именно по времени"... сравнивать бы не со всеми словами из словаря, а только длины, равной проверяемому слову?

Comment: Даже в этом случае всё плохо на словарях и текстах в которых все слова по 20 букв.

Comment: жаль, что тс не может дать ссылку на задачу...

Comment: @EzikBro олимпиадное программирование это не школьная олимпиада по информатике, где надо нарисовать блоксхему. Конкретный код решения отправляется на проверку через онлайн-систему. далее он прогоняется тестами на проверку корректности результата, тайм и мемори лимитов. Так что тут решение именно конкретный код, который удовлетворяет ограничениям.

Comment: @teran не знаю ни одной олимпиадной системы, в которой разрешается использовать сторонние модули. Только стандартный набор, в который jellyfish отнюдь не входит.

Comment: `import solution` - это не решение...

Comment: @EzikBro вы написали "решение задачи не код а алгоритм". Возможно это оказалось вырвано из контекста, но претензия моя была к этой фразе

Comment: @teran я сразу сказал, что это мое мнение. Дело в том, что любая олимпиадная задача (в том числе и по информатике) строится на какой-то идее, которую олимпиадник и должен найти и использовать в ходе решения. Конечно, задачу можно решить и грубой силой или просто альтернативным методом, но я не считаю это полноценным решением, ведь олимпиады нужны в том числе и для того, чтобы учиться новому. Из-за это код без описания, что он делает и как до него дошли, я также не считаю полноценным решением. Но повторюсь, это мое личное мнение, поэтому критиковать его бессмысленно.

Answer (score 2):

Это задача на особое хеширование.
Нужно всего-лишь сосчитать хеш для пар букв.

```
X_X_X_X (0-a)
_X_X_X_ (0-b)
XX__XX__XX__XX (1-a)
__XX__XX__XX__ (1-b)
XXXX____XXXX____ (2-a)
____XXXX____XXXX (2-b)
```

То-есть есть слова

```
vector<string> words;
```

И их хеши

```
array<array<unordered_map<size_t, vector<string*>>, 2>, 5> hashes;
```

И для проверки есть ли в словаре:

```
string* word_get(string s)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < hashes.size(); i++)
    {
        size_t ha = word_hasher(s, i);
        if (hashes[i][0].find(ha) == hashes[i][0].end() && 
            hashes[i][1].find(ha) == hashes[i][1].end()) 
            return nullptr;
    }

    // word final tests
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понял как надо просчитать хеш для пар букв, т.к. не сталкивался с хешированием до этого, не говоря уже о **особом** хешировании. Можете поподробней объяснить ваш алгоритм

Comment: Обычно хеш считается от всего слова, а для этой задачи нужно считать только от половины букв. Тоесть промто в функции хеширования учитывать только чётные\нечётные буквы.

Comment: Я про эту идею думал, но не довёл до реализации. Пять пар хешей, в каждой одно совпадение - это понятно. А что потом?

Comment: Взять из одной из пар вектора слов и проверять как раньше. И все 5 пар нужны только для слов из 17+ символов.

Comment: Корзина для `X_X_X_X` может быть очень велика. До 26^3. Получается, из пяти корзин которые совпали, надо выбрать самую маленькую. Так?

Comment: *Нужно всего-лишь* - ну это не дело, отвечайте, когда у вас будет что-то рабочее

Comment: @user7860670 не хочу полностью решать глупые(олимпиадные) задачи. Я лишь примерно описал, каким путём можно решить данную задачу. Вон рядом есть ответ с 21 хешами вместо 10.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал свой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string* vocab;
string* text;

int quantityOfWordsInVocab, quantityOfWordsInText;


void diff(int index)
{
    int howMany{ 0 };
    int k = 0;
    int sizeOfTextWord = text[index].size();
        for (int j = 0; j < quantityOfWordsInVocab; j++)
        {
            if (sizeOfTextWord != vocab[j].size()) {  continue; }

            while (k != vocab[j].size())
            {
                
                if (text[index][k] != vocab[j][k])
                {
                    howMany++;
                }
    
                k++;            
            }
            if (!(howMany >= 2))
            {
            
                cout << vocab[j] << '\n';
                return;
            }
            howMany = 0;
        }

    
        cout << "?\n";
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin >> quantityOfWordsInVocab >> quantityOfWordsInText;

    vocab = new string[quantityOfWordsInVocab];
    text = new string[quantityOfWordsInText];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < quantityOfWordsInVocab; i++)
    {
        cin >> vocab[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < quantityOfWordsInText; i++)
    {
        cin >> text[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    bool ok = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < quantityOfWordsInText; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < quantityOfWordsInVocab; j++)
        {       
            if (text[i] == vocab[j])
            {
                cout << text[i] << '\n';
                ok = true;
                break;
            }           
                    
        }
        if (!ok)
        {
            diff(i);
        }
        ok = false;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Работает достаточно быстро

Comment: Нет выбора "лексикографически минимального" похожего слова. Выдаётся первое похожее.

Comment: а точно, сделаю!